# Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated. How to fix this statement?

Tags: php

I have the following statement which worked fine before PHP 5.3 using the split function:

```
$command = split (" ", $tag[1]);
```

After upgrading to PHP 5.3, I get the Deprecated warning:

```
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated.
```

Comment: Have you look at the documentation on [`split()`](http://php.net/split)? In this case you need [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$command = explode(" ", $tag[1]);
```

This is the standard solution for this case.

If you need to match on a regular expression (rather than something simple like a space), use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). It's slower than `explode`, so there's no reason to use it unless you *need* a regex.

BTW to do the opposite (join array elements into a string), use [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 3):

From [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) page:

Tip

> split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is the suggested
>   alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of
>   regular expressions, it is faster to use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which doesn't
>   incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.

If you are going to split in " " you might consider explode to be a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Well the first thing someone should do is checking the documenation: [split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

It is recommended to use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) or [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)